# PHP arrays and {$property} syntax

Tags: php, arrays, properties

Please can someone explain this code to me:

```
<?php

class Model
{

    protected $dates = [];

    public function __get($property)
    {
        if (in_array($property, $this->dates)) {
            return new DateTime($this->{$property});
        }

        return $this->{$property};
    }

}

class User extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['createdAt'];

    protected $createdAt = '2016-01-01 12:35:15';
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['createdAt'];

    protected $createdAt = '2016-01-01 12:35:15';
}

$comment = new Comment;

var_dump($comment->createdAt->format('H:i'));
```

I don't get how he is using the array here. Is he accessing an index of the array by just using $property? And how does $this->{$property} work?

Funny, but I don't understand this code, although it's just a beginners example...

Kind regards,
Milan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to explain code is not acceptable at [so]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't get how he is using the array here.

He/She is using the `dates` array to auto-convert date property values to a proper `DateTime` object. If the property matches one of the elements in the `$this->dates` array, then the property value will be returned as a `DateTime` value otherwise the normal property value is returned.

> how does $this->{$property} work?

This is how you access a dynamic property on an object

```
// let's say $property is set to 'foo'
$this->{$property}

// is the same as
$ths->foo
```

---

**That is garbage code tho.**

The dynamic get/set of properties means that certain properties behave in special ways. As more *Model* properties are added, they leak into the PHP *Class* properties as well. It's a recipe for disaster.

Here's a better code example

```
class Util {
  static public function datetime($str) {
    return new DateTime($str);
  }
}

class Model {
  protected $attributes = [];

  protected $map_attributes = [];

  public function __construct($attributes = []) {
    $this->attributes = $attributes;
  }

  public function __set($property, $value) {
    $attributes[$property] = $value;
  }

  public function __get($property) {
    if (!array_key_exists($property, $this->attributes))
      return null;
    elseif (array_key_exists($property, $this->map_attributes))
      return call_user_func($this->map_attributes[$property], $this->attributes[$property]);
    else
      return $this->attributes[$property];
  }
}

class User extends Model {
  protected $map_attributes = [
    'created_at' => ['Util', 'datetime']
  ];
}

$u = new User(['foo' => 'bar', 'created_at' => '2016-01-01 12:35:15']);

echo $u->foo, PHP_EOL;                       // bar
echo $u->created_at->format('H:i'), PHP_EOL; // 12:35
```

<kbd>**[Run this code at REPL.it](https://repl.it/C8Z5)**</kbd>

Now all get/set Model properties are nicely sandboxed in a single `$this->attributes` array Class property. This prevents properties from littering properties all over `Model` or subclasses of `Model`.

Also, each class can arbitrarily map any property to another value by setting the proper mapping function in `$this->map_attributes`. This means that `Model::__get` doesn't need to be updated to support a new property->value mapping when a subclass needs to return a different type.

Consequently the ugly and hazardous `$this->{$property}` goes away, too. Dynamic property access has a use case, but I don't think this (the original code you posted) is one of them.